# HTML pattern [A-Za-z] says please match the requested format when i entire name like "john"

Tags: javascript, html, css

```html
<div class="name deets">
  <label for="idname" class="label">Name</label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="idname" pattern="[A-Za-z]" required>
</div>
```

[Firefox screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahpGd.png)

Answer (score 1):

So since I've given the 'required' tag, I must issue a minimum number of inputs in the pattern attribute, so the correct pattern tag would be:

```
pattern="[A-Za-z]{1,20}"
```

Answer (score 0):

The only problem you have with your current code is that you specified that the pattern must be only one character; this can be verified using the `:valid` pseudo-class:

```css
::placeholder {
  font-style: italic;
  color: hsl(0 10% 10%);
}

input:invalid {
  background-color: hsl(0 100% 80% / 0.5);
}

input:valid {
  background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="name deets">
  <label for="idname" class="label">Name</label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="idname" pattern="[A-Za-z]" required>
</div>
```

To correct this, you simply have to add the option to have multiple characters as follows (explanations are offered in the `<details>` elements within the demo):

```css
:root {
  --color-invalid: hsl(0 100% 80% / 0.5);
  --color-valid: hsl(120deg 61% 50% / 0.5);
}

::placeholder {
  font-style: italic;
  color: hsl(0 10% 10%);
}

div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  gap: 1em;
  inline-size: clamp(20em, 50vw, 900px);
  margin-block: 1em;
  margin-inline: auto;
  padding: 0.25em;
}

label {
  font-weight: 400;
  transition: font-weight 0.2s ease-in;
}

div:focus-within label {
  font-weight: 900;
}

label::after {
  content: ':';
}

input {
  background-color: var(--color);
  transition: color 0.3s ease-in;
}

input:focus-visible {
  outline: 0.3em solid var(--color);
  outline-offset: 0.3em;
}

input:invalid {
  --color: var(--color-invalid);
}

input:valid {
  --color: var(--color-valid);
}

code {
  color: hsl(120 100% 20%);
  background-color: hsl(0 0% 0% / 0.2);
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding-inline: 0.25em;
}

details {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

summary {
  cursor: pointer;
}

em {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<div class="name deets">
  <label for="idname1" class="label">Name</label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="eg: John" id="idname1" pattern="[A-Za-z]+" required>
  <details>
    <summary><code>pattern="[A-Za-z]+"</code></summary>
    <ol class="explanation">
      <li><code>[...]</code> specifies the acceptable characters,</li>
      <li><code>A-Z</code> specifies the range from (uppercase) A to (uppercase) Z,</li>
      <li><code>a-z</code> specifies the range from (lowercase) a to (lowercase) z,</li>
      <li><code>+</code> specifies at <em>least</em> one match of the preceding character (or range of characters).</li>
    </ol>
  </details>
</div>

<div class="name deets">
  <label for="idname2" class="label">Name</label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="eg: Jonny" id="idname2" pattern="[A-Za-z]{5,}" required>
  <details>
    <summary><code>pattern="[A-Za-z]{5,}"</code></summary>
    <ol class="explanation">
      <li><code>[...]</code> specifies the acceptable characters,</li>
      <li><code>A-Z</code> specifies the range from (uppercase) A to (uppercase) Z,</li>
      <li><code>a-z</code> specifies the range from (lowercase) a to (lowercase) z,</li>
      <li><code>{5,}</code> specifies a minimum of <em>5</em> matches with no upper-limt</li>
    </ol>
  </details>
</div>

<div class="name deets">
  <label for="idname3" class="label">Name</label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="eg: Marie-Antoinette" id="idname3" pattern="[A-Za-z-]{5,16}" required>
  <details>
    <summary><code>pattern="[A-Za-z]{5,16}"</code></summary>
    <ol class="explanation">
      <li><code>[...]</code> specifies the acceptable characters,</li>
      <li><code>A-Z</code> specifies the range from (uppercase) A to (uppercase) Z,</li>
      <li><code>a-z</code> specifies the range from (lowercase) a to (lowercase) z,</li>
      <li><code>-</code> permits a literal hyphen within the string,</li>
      <li><code>{5,16}</code> specifies a minimum of <em>5</em> and a maximum of <em>16</em> matches.</li>
    </ol>
  </details>
</div>

<div class="name deets">
  <label for="idname4" class="label">Name</label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="eg: Sally Ann" id="idname4" pattern="[A-Za-z\s-]{5,16}" required>
  <details>
    <summary><code>pattern="[A-Za-z\s-]{5,16}"</code></summary>
    <ol class="explanation">
      <li><code>[...]</code> specifies the acceptable characters,</li>
      <li><code>s</code> includes white-space characters within the permitted string,</li>
      <li><code>A-Z</code> specifies the range from (uppercase) A to (uppercase) Z,</li>
      <li><code>a-z</code> specifies the range from (lowercase) a to (lowercase) z,</li>
      <li><code>{5,16}</code> specifies a minimum of <em>5</em> and a maximum of <em>16</em> matches.</li>
    </ol>
  </details>
</div>

<div class="name deets">
  <label for="idname5" class="label">Name</label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="eg: Sally Ann" id="idname5" pattern="[A-Z]{1,}[a-zA-Z\s-]{3,}[^\s-]" required>
  <details>
    <summary><code>pattern="[A-Z][a-zA-Z\s-]{3,}[^\s-]"</code></summary>
    <ol class="explanation">
      <li><code>[...]</code> specifies the acceptable characters,</li>
      <li><code>[A-Z]</code> requires one uppercase character in the range from A-Z</li>
      <li><code>[a-zA-Z\s-]</code> followed by another character from the range of <em>a</em> to <em>z</em>, uppercase or lowercase, also permitting white-space or a literal hyphen <em>-</em> character</li>
      <li><code>{3,}</code> specifies a minimum of <em>5</em> with no maximum number,</li>
      <li><code>[^\s-]</code> and cannot end with either a white-space character or hyphen literal, the caret <code>^</code> at the first position within the square brackets acts as a <em>not</em> operator for the other characters.</li>
    </ol>
  </details>
</div>
```

Reference:

- [`pattern` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern).

Bibliography:

- [Regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
- "[Regular expressions syntax cheatsheet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Cheatsheet)," Mozilla Developer Network.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem you have with your current code is that you specified that the pattern must be only one character; this can be verified using the `:valid` pseudo-class:

```css
::placeholder {
  font-style: italic;
  color: hsl(0 10% 10%);
}

input:invalid {
  background-color: hsl(0 100% 80% / 0.5);
}

input:valid {
  background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="name deets">
  <label for="idname" class="label">Name</label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="idname" pattern="[A-Za-z]" required>
</div>
```

To correct this, you simply have to add the option to have multiple characters as follows (explanations are offered in the `<details>` elements within the demo):

```css
:root {
  --color-invalid: hsl(0 100% 80% / 0.5);
  --color-valid: hsl(120deg 61% 50% / 0.5);
}

::placeholder {
  font-style: italic;
  color: hsl(0 10% 10%);
}

div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  gap: 1em;
  inline-size: clamp(20em, 50vw, 900px);
  margin-block: 1em;
  margin-inline: auto;
  padding: 0.25em;
}

label {
  font-weight: 400;
  transition: font-weight 0.2s ease-in;
}

div:focus-within label {
  font-weight: 900;
}

label::after {
  content: ':';
}

input {
  background-color: var(--color);
  transition: color 0.3s ease-in;
}

input:focus-visible {
  outline: 0.3em solid var(--color);
  outline-offset: 0.3em;
}

input:invalid {
  --color: var(--color-invalid);
}

input:valid {
  --color: var(--color-valid);
}

code {
  color: hsl(120 100% 20%);
  background-color: hsl(0 0% 0% / 0.2);
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding-inline: 0.25em;
}

details {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

summary {
  cursor: pointer;
}

em {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<div class="name deets">
  <label for="idname1" class="label">Name</label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="eg: John" id="idname1" pattern="[A-Za-z]+" required>
  <details>
    <summary><code>pattern="[A-Za-z]+"</code></summary>
    <ol class="explanation">
      <li><code>[...]</code> specifies the acceptable characters,</li>
      <li><code>A-Z</code> specifies the range from (uppercase) A to (uppercase) Z,</li>
      <li><code>a-z</code> specifies the range from (lowercase) a to (lowercase) z,</li>
      <li><code>+</code> specifies at <em>least</em> one match of the preceding character (or range of characters).</li>
    </ol>
  </details>
</div>

<div class="name deets">
  <label for="idname2" class="label">Name</label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="eg: Jonny" id="idname2" pattern="[A-Za-z]{5,}" required>
  <details>
    <summary><code>pattern="[A-Za-z]{5,}"</code></summary>
    <ol class="explanation">
      <li><code>[...]</code> specifies the acceptable characters,</li>
      <li><code>A-Z</code> specifies the range from (uppercase) A to (uppercase) Z,</li>
      <li><code>a-z</code> specifies the range from (lowercase) a to (lowercase) z,</li>
      <li><code>{5,}</code> specifies a minimum of <em>5</em> matches with no upper-limt</li>
    </ol>
  </details>
</div>

<div class="name deets">
  <label for="idname3" class="label">Name</label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="eg: Marie-Antoinette" id="idname3" pattern="[A-Za-z-]{5,16}" required>
  <details>
    <summary><code>pattern="[A-Za-z]{5,16}"</code></summary>
    <ol class="explanation">
      <li><code>[...]</code> specifies the acceptable characters,</li>
      <li><code>A-Z</code> specifies the range from (uppercase) A to (uppercase) Z,</li>
      <li><code>a-z</code> specifies the range from (lowercase) a to (lowercase) z,</li>
      <li><code>-</code> permits a literal hyphen within the string,</li>
      <li><code>{5,16}</code> specifies a minimum of <em>5</em> and a maximum of <em>16</em> matches.</li>
    </ol>
  </details>
</div>

<div class="name deets">
  <label for="idname4" class="label">Name</label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="eg: Sally Ann" id="idname4" pattern="[A-Za-z\s-]{5,16}" required>
  <details>
    <summary><code>pattern="[A-Za-z\s-]{5,16}"</code></summary>
    <ol class="explanation">
      <li><code>[...]</code> specifies the acceptable characters,</li>
      <li><code>s</code> includes white-space characters within the permitted string,</li>
      <li><code>A-Z</code> specifies the range from (uppercase) A to (uppercase) Z,</li>
      <li><code>a-z</code> specifies the range from (lowercase) a to (lowercase) z,</li>
      <li><code>{5,16}</code> specifies a minimum of <em>5</em> and a maximum of <em>16</em> matches.</li>
    </ol>
  </details>
</div>

<div class="name deets">
  <label for="idname5" class="label">Name</label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="eg: Sally Ann" id="idname5" pattern="[A-Z]{1,}[a-zA-Z\s-]{3,}[^\s-]" required>
  <details>
    <summary><code>pattern="[A-Z][a-zA-Z\s-]{3,}[^\s-]"</code></summary>
    <ol class="explanation">
      <li><code>[...]</code> specifies the acceptable characters,</li>
      <li><code>[A-Z]</code> requires one uppercase character in the range from A-Z</li>
      <li><code>[a-zA-Z\s-]</code> followed by another character from the range of <em>a</em> to <em>z</em>, uppercase or lowercase, also permitting white-space or a literal hyphen <em>-</em> character</li>
      <li><code>{3,}</code> specifies a minimum of <em>5</em> with no maximum number,</li>
      <li><code>[^\s-]</code> and cannot end with either a white-space character or hyphen literal, the caret <code>^</code> at the first position within the square brackets acts as a <em>not</em> operator for the other characters.</li>
    </ol>
  </details>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/s64geqbh/).

Reference:

- [`pattern` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern).

Bibliography:

- [Regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
- "[Regular expressions syntax cheatsheet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Cheatsheet)," Mozilla Developer Network.